# Modular symbols, Manin symbols, two and three term relation

Tags: modular-forms, group-cohomology, modular-group

Maybe someone could help me out. I consider a $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-module $\Omega$. We set
\begin{align}
S:=\left(\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{array}\right) \ \mathrm{and} \  U:=\left(\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 1\end{array}\right).
\end{align}
I want to compute the quotient
\begin{align}
\Omega/\left((1+S) \ \Omega \oplus (1+U+U^2) \ \Omega\right).
\end{align}
Trivially in this quotient the so called two and three term relations
\begin{align}
\omega + S\omega=0 \ \mathrm{and} \  \omega+U\omega+U^2\omega=0
\end{align}
hold. So I am wondering if there is maybe a connection to the group of $\Omega$-valued $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-invariant modular symbols or something in this direction?

Thanks for granted :)

Edit: Maybe I should be more precise: The module I consider is (more or less) the free module generated by $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{Q})$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$-acts via Möbius transformations.